# creating apps not for selling

Tags: ipad

I have to create interactive animations for iPad for a private firm. I have to install the app on all employee's IPad. I dont want to put it on app store. As its only private to a firm.
What shld I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are less than 100 iOS devices total over the year, and these private apps can be reinstalled or re-provisioned around a couple times per year, the private firm can use Ad Hoc app deployment under a standard iOS company enrollment, which is cheaper and involves less paperwork than Enterprise distribution.

You should have the company apply for their own company developer enrollment so you don't use up your allotment of 100 test devices, which could put you out of business (for up to a year) if your current test device has a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

This: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Or if you are limited on funds, you can add each iPad as a development device and install it manually.  Headache, but free.

Comment: You can reduce the headache part with wireless distribution. See - http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2010/12/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs.php. there are also products like TestFlight that make this easier (I haven't used them though). You will still be using up your allocation of 100 development devices though.

Comment: Which might be a pain because the certificates will expire rather soon and need reinstall.